# How to indicate network activity in status bar in iOS 8 extension app

Tags: ios

I'd like to show network activity while loading web page in iOS 8 extension app.

But can't use `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` in extension app.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;    
    return YES;
}
```

How to show network activity in extension app?

Answer (score 0):

iOS extensions have limitation to reach some APIs. These are defined on [ExtensionOverview](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html).

> Access a sharedApplication object, and so cannot use any of the methods on that object
>
> Use any API marked in header files with the NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE macro, or similar unavailability macro, or any API in an unavailable framework
>
> For example, in iOS 8.0, the HealthKit framework and EventKit UI framework are unavailable to app extensions.
>
> Access the camera or microphone on an iOS device (an iMessage app, unlike other app extensions, does have access to these resources, as long as it correctly configures the NSCameraUsageDescription and NSMicrophoneUsageDescription Info.plist keys)
>
> Perform long-running background tasks
>
> The specifics of this limitation vary by platform, as described in the extension point chapters in this document.
>
> (An app extension can initiate uploads or downloads using an NSURLSession object, with results of those operations reported to the containing app.)
>
> Receive data using AirDrop
>
> (An app extension can send data using AirDrop in the same way an app does: by employing the UIActivityViewController class.)

Try using [UIActivityIndicatorView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityindicatorview).